# WKInerfaceLabel is placed above WKInerfaceTable but don't want it to scroll with WKInterfaceTable

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacetable

I have placed a WKInerfaceLabel above table but I don't want my WKInerfaceTable to scroll with table. How to achieve it in Apple Watch.

Comment: Your intention is not clear: do you want to disable scrolling on `UITableView`, or disable scrolling of `UILabel` you have above `UITableView`?

Comment: I have a label above WKInterfaceTable you can think of it like table header. I don't want that label to scroll with WKInterfaceTable

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't ever mistake WKInterfaceTable for UITable. The 2 look the same but they're not. Sadly, this can't be done. But you can sit your InterfaceController's title property to contain your text label.

[image]

Comment: I already have a title for my controller. Is there any other way out for it.